# Use lattice xyplot for grouped data with points and lines

Tags: r, lattice

I wish to make a single-panel graph in lattice that shows data (y) from several groups (g) with superimposed lines showing predicted values (y_pred). I generate example data below:

```
d <- data.frame(x = rep(1:100,2), g = factor(rep(c('a','b'), each = 100))) 
d$y_pred <- -0.1*x + 0.001*x^2
d$y_pred <- with(d, ifelse(g=='a', y_pred+2,y_pred))
d$y <- d$y_pred + rnorm(nrow(d),0,1)
```

Using 'type=c('p','l'), distribute.type=TRUE does not work, nor does my attempt at making a panel:

```
xyplot(y + y_pred ~ x, data = d,
    groups = g,
    panel = panel.superpose,
    panel.groups=function(...){
        panel.xyplot(x, y, type='p')
        panel.xyplot(x, y_pred, type='l')
    }
    )
```

What should I do here?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you can do this with latticeExtra

```
dat <- xyplot(y ~ x, data=d,
    groups = g,
    type="p"
    )
dat

dat + layer(panel.xyplot(x=x, y=y_pred,
        groups = g,
        type="l",
        subscripts=TRUE),
    data=d)
```

But this is really finicky and non-robust. The 'dat + layer()' code will render properly if it is the first thing I run after starting the program, but after that it will frequently render with several of lines for different groups missing.